# Are competitive sports an effective way to change my Spartiates' life perspective?

Tags: psychology, strategy, sports

I am creating a world in which a society exists that is heavily inspired that ancient [Sparta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparta), specifically with a focus on [Spartiates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spartiate) and their military education, the [agoge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agoge). A character in the story is trying to change the life perspective of a group of male Spartiates, who were trained from a very young age to fight in military battles, through competitive sports, specifically [Basketball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basketball).

**Therefore I am looking for information about the effect of competitive sports on the psychology of teenagers with extreme levels of aggression potential with the goal of reducing said aggression potential.**

Can I integrate these teenagers into today's society after working with them and introducing them to Basketball?

There are a few differences between the agoge and the training these teenagers went through:

- Kids are trained in all sorts of martial arts.
- Military training started at the age of 3.
- They were trained 16 hours a day, 7 days a week.
- Each Spartiate has killed at least 5 kids - some of which have been close friends.
- All Spartiates have average intelligence.
- All Spartiates are able to read and write.

The teenagers in this specific group are between 15 and 19 years old.

I would like to paint these teenagers as veteran warriors who did not learn how to smile, born in a world where love did not exist and their sole purpose is to kill or die.

Why Basketball? The protagonist is the coach of a Basketball team, which means that he knows a lot about the sport. The teenagers will listen to the coach as if he was any other instructor they have had over the course of their military education.

**Would introducing these teenagers to Basketball be a suitable way to reduce their aggression potential in the long run to an acceptable level for today's society?**

Comment: You might find a search for "rehabilitation of child soldiers" usefull. What you describe comes pretty close to what child soldiers live through today and the phenomenon is present in several war zones all over the world. Different organizations use different approaches, but non-violent competitive sports are used in virtually every one of them. From my understanding, unfortunately, sports alone are not enough to rehabilitate a traumatized child / teen.

Comment: @YElm I think the difference of Child soldier than the Spartiates is the "Formality" of the profession, They don't cower when outnumbered, don't fear when tortured, they don't think twice when ordered. Modern military children are somewhat "not on par" with the training of  Spartiates, They are not traumatized children, they are the chosen few who was chosen to live as soldier and die by the blade. a bit confused right now... Thank you for your insight!

Comment: Having played basketball and knowing how hard is the fight in the 3 seconds area, I am not sure basket is the best choice. A well addressed elbow hit can hurt a lot. Have you though about volleyball, where you have no physical contact with your opponent?

Comment: The basic problem with this approach is that the actual historical Spartans actually participated in competitive sports; this did not change their world view. See the [list of ancient Olympic victors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ancient_Olympic_victors) on Wikipedia. Notably, the first woman known to be remembered as an Olympic victor was [Cynisca of Sparta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cynisca).

Comment: @AlexP, good point, but also worth nothing that in some ancient Olympic sports killing/severely hurting the opponent was tolerated.

Comment: @L.Dutch: Yes it was and to a large extent it still is. For example, I've never heard of a boxer or a footballer being prosecuted for breaking the bones of an opponent.

Comment: @AlexP While I agree in principle, there was at least [one case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Todd_Bertuzzi%E2%80%93Steve_Moore_incident) of a hockey enforcer being charged with assault, in two different jurisdictions (one where the game was played, one where the injured player was from). This was a clear case of retaliation and headhunting. The offending player plead guilty and got probation.

Comment: @kingledion: That's a reinforcement of the idea that purely sport-related violence is both expected and tolerated, isn't it?

Comment: *Each Spartiate has killed at least 5 kids - some of which have been close friends* That's a group of psychopaths, not kids.  There is **no one** who knows how to undo this level of damage.  Sports isn't even in the picture.  Think serial killers.  Even the modern military would not touch them.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

#### The Power of Sports is useful, But Overstated

I am a combat veteran of two wars and I found competitive sports useful to provide a distraction and work off excess anxiety and restlessness, but frankly there never was an Oscar worthy moment where the power of sportsmanship and football suddenly made all my problems go away. Military indoctrination, mental conditioning, and war trauma just really don't go away because you magically channel it all into a sports team. It's really just a pleasant distraction for a while that serves as a constructive way to burn off some negativity in a positive manner. I understand the misconception, too.

Most people have never been in a military unit, undergone any formal military training, or gone to war. The closest most people ever get to having a regimented and competitive lifestyle like that is sports, so it's only natural to think that if one could just channel themselves into sports that it only stands to reason that they would just be putting said conditioning and experience to good use and get over it. There are surface similarities, but a sports team and a military unit are worlds apart. Nothing the vast majority of civilians have experienced ever comes close to what being in war is like, so it's understandable that they don't understand the nature of combat, so I will give you a bit of an eye into the military mind and maybe you can form some more accurate conclusions from it.

#### They Will NOT Listen to the Coach If he is a Civilian

We have a near racial slur for you people. *Civvies*, or *civs*. A *Civ* is a soft, naive and docile thing that doesn't really understand hardship, sacrifice, dedication, or brotherhood. They either fear us, or are trying to get our attention by pretending to "get" us. When you are a vet hearing most civvies talk about the military is kind of like asking a 6 year old to explain what they think college is like. When you show up for a therapy session or for psychological counseling or even get treatments for a past wound and the person is a civvie it's pretty disappointing. You know one of a few things will happen. They will often come across as patronizing and simpering by trying to impress you with how much they "get it." Another thing they do is try so hard to tiptoe around the elephant in the room that it becomes annoying and awkward.

Finding out that the person you are meeting with is a combat veteran is a huge relief, because you can both communicate on the same wavelength. There is a mutual respect there as well as a shared experience. It is my advice that your coach be a retired very senior ranking enlisted man, who has extensive combat and military history. They will respect, resonate, and trust him more. He's not a "dumb civvie" talking about things he's never done or seen. He's one of them, he doesn't have to pretend he "gets it." It's just instinctively understood that he does without him having to undermine his own authority by being patronizing or offering advice on matters he doesn't have experience with. Being a previous senior staff NCO also generates a lot of respect because first, he's been a grunt foot slogger just like them who worked his way through the ranks just like they hope to do some day. It shouldn't be an officer, because the enlisted/officer relationship is too formal and would get in the way of the mentor-ship relationship.

#### It Should be Built on a Military Style Training Regimen

One of the reasons that sports might NOT appeal to somebody like this is because they lack weight. In the military nothing you do is pointless. It may seem that way sometimes, but the point is ALWAYS to learn some valuable skill, mindset, or achieve a better physical condition. When every action of your life is planned to make you better at your job and increase your survival depends on your ability to perform this job when you get back to the civilian world it's kind of weird. "Wow, these people really get worked up over something so stupid." When I run 8 miles it's because I need to make sure that I can locate, close with, and destroy my enemy. When I lift weights it's so I can carry a wounded brother better, or get a machine gun into position that saves my squad. "These people just do it because they want to put a ball into a basket better. How stupid and pointless." In the military as a combatant you do not just have a job, you have a purpose for existing. It is your sole purpose in life to either be winning wars, or training to win wars. These guys are going to just turn away from a purpose they were literally bred and born to fulfill to toss a ball? Not unless the training of it resonates. To do so it has to feel familiar.

#### There Will be no Magic "Oscar Moment"

I was not subjected to military conditioning until I was an adult, and I was a volunteer. I still have issues with a lot of stuff, including a recurring smoldering disdain for the often petty and trivial things that people always seem to get so worked up over. I suffer from an inability to feel much pity for much of anyone. In war weakness gets one or their brothers killed. Weakness is a sin and when somebody is trying to make me sympathize with them I often instead feel an irrational disgust and hatred instead. These are all issues I still deal with years later. These guys were conditioned from *birth*. They are going to have it even a lot worse than I do. It was never a choice for them, and they have very very little context to compare any of their experiences to that are not military in nature. Expecting them to suddenly be okay after winning a championship or something is just irrational. You need to set realistic expectations for these young men to achieve. They will probably never be totally alright. They can only really hope to learn healthy coping mechanisms and try to manage their symptoms. There will always be a disconnect there and there will always need to be a willful internal struggle to try to use the experience for good. It's been several years and I still sometimes have trouble. It's not about "getting over it" so much as learning to live with it.

#### Keep Them Separate from Normal Kids

Back to the civvies thing, except imagine somebody who has spent 15 to 19 years training to kill getting into a fist fight with a normal athletic, but mentally soft jock whose biggest claim to toughness is a few bloody noses and puffy lips in schoolyard scuffles. These spartan kids aren't really kids, they're honed killers. They are people to whom death is a suitable conflict resolution strategy. They're literally going to rip even your biggest "toughest" teen jock or bully apart. I'm talking broken bones, possible brain damage or all out death here. Introducing them to normal kids is going to be a very slow and gradual process that doesn't begin until well towards the end of the program once the members have demonstrated a clear and obvious improvement.

#### Summary

The sports are ultimately just going to be one tool among many that are used to ease these guys into a normal life. Don't expect all of them to make it, and even possibly expect some of them to actually wish to return to their old life, maybe even possibly do so. Hell, I actually *miss* Afghanistan and Iraq. I had a very simple and clearly defined purpose there and an easily quantified value and place within the hierarchy. I miss my brothers and I miss being so focused and having everything so clearly defined and understood. I imagine that at least a few of these kids will not see themselves as liberated and maybe even want to go back. The Sports Regimen could be a useful part of the recovery process, but it's not going to be the only one by far.

Comment: A reasonable answer with actual - and useful - background data to support it. Thanks for sharing your experience.

Comment: I gotta say, I have an almost diametrically opposite experience. 13 years of uniformed service and the times my life was threatened were a rounding error. 99% of my service was boredom and contempt for contractors and staff officers. Warfighting in the 2000s is more Office Space than 300. Did you ever think you'd make a powerpoint presentation in a sandy ditch? I was much more engaged by base soccer and football leagues, on shore duty and abroad, than I ever was over there, staring at nothing, sweating, trying to get sand out of my skivvies (ps don't try, it only makes it worse).

Comment: The key difference between civil and military life and mind AFAICS is a vastly different moral code. At war, various deeds that are normally felonies are fair game and necessity (including theft/robbery, murder, torture and generally solving problems with violence), and the priority is victory over human life and limb. Sports also prioritize collective victory over individual gain, but go nowhere near this fundamental priority inversion.

Comment: Pretty useful insight into the differences between a combat vet, a normal vet, and a civilian. Interesting. Thanks for sharing. This answer has a lot more value than 19 upvotes. Should be at 300+ honestly. I'm not exaggerating.

Comment: "*When you show up for a therapy session or for psychological counseling or even get treatments for a past wound and the person is a civvie it's pretty disappointing. [snip]*" This happened to me. EMT, was recommended to psych counseling after a nasty MCI, and the guy just... didn't get it. I gave up after thirty minutes of (not literally, but almost) "and how did that make you *feel*?" I'm disappointed, but not that surprised, that the military has the same issue.

Comment: Kingdelion, I understand completeley, my service was a pretty rare occurence. I spent over half of my time in forward deployed and completeley expeditionary. Most military never even leave the country, somehow I just managed to land my ass in back to back combat deployments and all of our time stateside was spent training for the next deployment. I think its safe to say my expierience is pretty uncommon nowdays.

Comment: Had similar issues with counseling for my own PTSD (non-military) and at this stage I don't think I'd even waste time talking to a counselor who could not answer "yes" to "Have you ever had this yourself ?".  I don't think they have solutions anyway but won't admit it, which is really just frustrating and not useful (for me).  Good luck and interesting answer.

Comment: A little tip: to notify someone in a comment you need to write an "@" in front of their username. It even helps you with an autocomplete function because typos in a username will prevent the system from notifying the person you wanted to notify. You can notify one person per comment and the OP will always be notified automatically. For example you would need to write @kingledion somewhere in your comment (like I just did) to make this user aware of your previous comment.

Comment: @TCAT117 with all these data, I want your honest opinion, wars back then are different from wars now. Will Spartiates even listen to a WWII Veteran? Just curious though...

Comment: @Mr.J In my expierience warriors generally have a pretty mutual respect for eachother regardless of background and region. They tend to contrast and compare similarities as often as differences.

Comment: FWIW, totalitarian societies are the closest you can get to military in civilian life ;) _"Hell, I actually miss Afghanistan and Iraq. I had a very simple and clearly defined purpose there and an easily quantified value and place within the hierarchy. I miss my brothers and I miss being so focused and having everything so clearly defined and understood."_ -- replace "Afganistan and Iraq" with "USSR" and you get _exactly_ the sentiments of its former citizens (me included) :-) [That's what makes totalitarism so enticing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Third_Wave_(experiment)).